# Sharing Jinja2 templates between Pylons and Django applications

Tags: django, pylons, jinja2

I'm writing a couple of Jinja2 templates that basically implement some common grid layouts.  I'd like to be able to share this 'library' of templates between a Pylons app and Django app.

I've hit a minor stumbling block in that Django's template context is accessible from the "top-level" of the template, whereas Pylons wraps your context inside the thread local `c` (or `tmpl_context`) variable.

Here are some analogous examples that demonstrate this.

### Django

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

ctx = {}
ctx['name'] = 'John'

return render_to_response('hello.html', ctx)
```

hello.html:

```
Hello {{ name }}
```

### Pylons

```
from pylons import tmpl_context as c
from myapp.lib.base import render

c.name = 'John'
return render('hello.html')
```

hello.html:

```
Hello {{ c.name }}
```

What I'm trying to do is make it so that `hello.html` is the same across both frameworks.

One way I see to do it is by wrapping the Django `render_to_response` and do something like this:

```
ctx['c'] = ctx
```

But that just doesn't feel right.  Anybody see other alternatives to this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

How dated is your version of Pylons?  `render` seems to be deprecated in favor of `render_jinja2`.  Granted, the [Jinja2 documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/2/documentation/integration#pylons) mislabels it as `render_jinja`, and the [Pylons documentation](http://pylonshq.com/docs/en/0.9.7/modules/templating/#module-contents) doesn't show it at all, but the [Pylons 1.0 source code](http://pylonshq.com/project/pylonshq/browser/pylons/templating.py) does include it and imply its usage.

Or if you're stuck with an older version of Pylons, you can exploit the fact that setting `c.name` is the same as setting `c.__dict__['name']`, and similarly for all its attributes.  This makes it easy to set all of c's attributes if you have the ctx dict handy.

```
ctx = {'name': 'John'}

# Django
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
render_to_response('hello.html', ctx)

# old Pylons?
from pylons import tmpl_context as c
from pylons.templating import render
c.__dict__.update(ctx)
render('hello.html')

# new Pylons
from pylon.templating import render_jinja2
render_jinja2('hello.html', ctx)
```

Also, I'm surprised that the old Pylons named the variable in the template based on what you named the object that you imported.  Are you sure that c isn't passed as an argument to `render`?

Disclaimer: I don't have Django or Pylons installed, so I can't test either of my suggestions.

Comment: I am using Pylons 1.0.  The function `myapp.lib.base.render` calls `render_jinja2` under the hood.  Pylons generated this wrapper when I created my project and I told it to use Jinja2.

Comment: Also, Pylons makes the context available to the template as both `tmpl_context` (legacy) and `c` (recommended).  How you import that module into your controller doesn't really impact how it is named in the template as far as I can tell.  

It doesn't have to be passed as an argument because Pylons uses some thread-local voodoo to make module-level things work on a per-request basis.  In other words, I could have imported it as `ctx` or whatever in my module, but Pylons would still make it available as `tmpl_context` and `c` to my template.

Comment: I see...I guess I don't know much about Pylons code.  Does `__dict__.update` help?  What happens if you call `render_jinja2` directly?

Comment: I'm a little confused because at some level, Jinja2 **does** accept `**kwargs`, so there must be a way to pass them instead of going through `c`.  Worst case, you could just use the Jinja2 API to render the templates yourself, and manually pass `c`, `c.__dict__`, `ctx`, etc.

Comment: I haven't done it yet, but I think the solution is going to involve tweaking the Django side to let the context processors execute, then take the resulting context and make it available to the templates as `c` so that it mimics what Pylons does.  That's if I want to keep using `render_jinja2` as-is which works with the thread-local voodoo.  Or, I could probably implement my own version of Pylons' `render_jinja2` that puts the thread-local context directly as the context instead of passing it in as `c` or `tmpl_context`.  I'll post an update if I get it working.